# Using parent object's properties inside jQuery function and other methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

First of all: I don't know exactly how to call everyting since I am quite new to the more OOP way of writing javascript, so I'll try to explain everything as good as possible.

My problem is that I want to access properties inside an object ( so I can use the `this`-keyword. This works fine as long as I am in the scope of the object. When I go outside the scope, I would like to access those properties while I can't use the `this`-keyword anymore.
My code:

```
var Octa = Octa || function () {
     this._initialize();
};

Octa.prototype = {
      string: 'Foo',

      _initialize: function () {
           console.log(this.string); //Output: "Foo"
           this.othermethod();
      }
}

var Octa = new Octa();
```

But when I have a method within an `Octa` method, so outside the scope where I can't use `this` anymore to get `Octa`'s properties, I can't reach the properties within `Octa`.
For example:

```
othermethod: function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: this.globalUrl + 'content/language/lang.' + l + '.php',
        data: {
            ajax: true
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
           Octa.lang = response;
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lang)); //Output: null, which means Octa.lang wasn't reachable in the ajax success event (the ajax request was successful). 
 }
```

Is there a way to reach the scope of `Octa` within other objects? Or within jQuery callbacks since the same problem occurs there.
I hope my problem is understandable and if not, I'll try to give more clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: $.ajax was just an example. It doesn't matter what I use, when I go outside the scop of `Octa`, I can't reach it. But I'll read the other post anyway. Thanks!

Comment: _$.ajax was just an example_ I would recommend you remove `$.ajax` as on first look question is fit to close as dupe.

Comment: i not understand your problem, in sample that you provide - same issue as in duplicated question. Can you explain where you see problem and provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This seems very dangerous: `var Octa = new Octa();` Aren't you overwriting your own class here? Concerning the scope, you could try binding the success callback to the Octa instance. Or just save all your Octa instance objects somewhere and have a way to reference them. But euh, as written, your console.log will always return null, since it isn't inside the success callback, so it gets run before the ajax call finishes.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! Turned out that there weren't any problem. I have to idea why I encountered them in the past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply refer back to `this` inside the function scope:

```
...,
someMethod: function () {
    var self = this,
        ajaxOptions = this.settings.ajaxOptions;

    // note we can still refer to 'this' at this level
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(this.ajaxDone).fail(this.ajaxFail);

    // the function scope changes for the deffered handlers so you can access by reference of 'this' => self
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function(data, status, xhr){
        self.ajaxDone(data, status, xhr)
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        self.ajaxFail(xhr, status, error);
    });
},
ajaxDone: function(data, status, xhr) {},
ajaxFail: function(xhr, status, error) {},
...
```

Hope this makes sense.

Now there's also a `.bind()` function that can be used to bind function scope to a parameter:

```
$.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function(){
    this.ajaxDone();
}.bind(this));
```

You'll have to use a polyfill to support older browsers. It's much more easier to use `var self` imho.

Comment: Since I didn't know about the bind() method and it could be very usefull in the future, I giving you the credits of answering my question.